# SQLite query returns NULL values while trying to update rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a multi-step form in android using SQLite db. 
My problem is, I want to update one column in username(primary key), but the db give me two row and a null value.

username ---------------- password -------------- active
myusername--------------mypass---------------------null
null--------------------------null------------------------yes

*username, password, fname, lname, active* is my columns in my 'user' table.

**SqliteHelper.java**

```
public boolean saveUser(String fname, String lname, String username, String password) {
    Cursor cursor = getUser(username);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("fname", fname);
    contentValues.put("lname", lname);
    contentValues.put("password", password);

    long result;
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        // added fname, lname, password
        contentValues.put("username", username);
        result = db.insert("users", null, contentValues);
    } else {
        result = db.update("users", contentValues, "fname=?", new String[] { fname });
        result = db.update("users", contentValues, "lname=?", new String[] { lname });
        result = db.update("users", contentValues, "username=?", new String[] { username });
        result = db.update("users", contentValues, "password=?", new String[] { password });
    }

    if(result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public long  saveUser1(String active) {
    Cursor cursor = getUser(active);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("active", active);
    long result;
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        result = db.insert("users", null, contentValues);
    } else {
        result = db.update("users", contentValues, "active=?", new String[] { active });
    }
    return db.update("users", contentValues, "active=?", new String[] { active });

}

public Cursor getUser(String username) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?";
    return  db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] { username });
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void save(View view) {
    // added fname, lname, password
    fname = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
    lname = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString();
    username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3)).getText().toString();
    password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4)).getText().toString();

    if (username.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    boolean result = sqliteHelper.saveUser(fname, lname, username, password);
    if (result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to save!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Next.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Next.java**

```
 public void save(View view) {
     long result = sqliteHelper.saveUser1(active);           

 }
```

Comment: A suggestion is to try and create a minimal example that demonstrates the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Next.java` class you are passing **active** in `saveUser1()` method, which is a boolean string I guess. And that method pass that **active** boolean string as **username** to check that if that user (with username 'yes' / 'no') already exists, which is wrong.

Also your `saveUser1()` method implementation is not correct. You are putting all db operation results in the **result** value, but never returned it.

**Edit:**

```
public long  saveUser1(String username, String active) {
    Cursor cursor = getUser(username);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("active", active);
    long result;
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        result = db.insert("users", null, contentValues);
    } else {
        result = db.update("users", contentValues, "username=?", new String[] { username });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: ahh, okay. thank you. But how I can improve that?? I have no idea

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you a possible solution. Try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: hi @Fayee, can you show the details like what data you saved into DB and then what you retrieved from the queries? If you don't send the inputs properly then you can't expect correct results. I hope you understand that I just share a possible solution, hence I don't have the whole data flow of your application.